# I keep getting IsADirectory error

Tags: python, html, replace, error-handling, directory

So, i'm writing a program to rewrite HTML code. It reads from a file, changes the selected text and saves that file in a different folder. It keeps returning with *IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/Users/Glenn/jack/HTML_Task/dest'*. I have googled it etc. but cannot solve the issue. Below is my code. (I am using a Mac)

```
    # HTML Rewriter

    ## Read from HTML file (from src folder)
    ## Replace http/ with / or use variables (ask user?)
    ## Write to new HTML files with same filename
    ## Put into dest folder

    import re
    import os

    file = open("2016_06_06_UK_BackToSchool.html").read()
    text_filtered = re.sub(r'http://', '/', file)
    print (text_filtered)

    with open ("2016_06_06_UK_BackToSchool.html", "wt") as out_file:
        out_file.write(text_filtered)

    with open(os.path.join('/Users/Glenn/jack/HTML_Task/dest',), "w") as out_file:
        os.rename('2016_06_06_UK_BackToSchool.html','/Users/Glenn/jack/HTML_Task/dest')
```

Comment: replace ``'/Users/Glenn/jack/HTML_Task/dest'`` with ``r'C:/Users/Glenn/jack/HTML_Task/dest'`` if the directory name is indeed ``C:``

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I'm on a Mac

Comment: just use the full path and add the ``r`` in front of the string **or** escape the slashes with slashes (replace ``/`` with ``//``)

Comment: @Ev.Kounis - IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '//Users//Glenn//jack//HTML_Task//dest'

Comment: run this: ``print(os.path.isdir(r'/Users/Glenn/jack/HTML_Task/dest'))``. If it returns False, then the path you are providing is not a directory

Comment: @ Ev.Kounis - Returns as True

Comment: actually just remove the last ``with`` statement.. you dont need to open the file to rename it.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis - Then this happens - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''

Comment: add this ``os.chdir('/Users/Glenn/jack/HTML_Task/dest')`` in the mix. just before the line that raises the error.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Glenn/jack/HTML_Task/src/HTML Rewriter.py", line 19, in <module>
    with open(os.path.join('//Users//Glenn//jack//HTML_Task//dest',), "w") as out_file:
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '//Users//Glenn//jack//HTML_Task//dest'